# Install the latest gcc on Pygoscelis Papua (Gentoo)

Tags: gentoo, gcc

I would like to try out Gentoo and I started a Pygoscelis Papua instance on Amazon EC2.

How do I install the latest version of `gcc` to compile my programs?

I tried

```
emerge -u gcc
gcc-config -l
```

as it says in "[Upgrading GCC](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Upgrading_GCC)" section of Gentoo wiki, but it only shows one option of gcc 4.7.3; I'd like to use 4.9.0 or 4.9.1.

Comment: First of all, Pygoscelis Papua rather sound like describing Ubuntu.  To your problem: GCC is not officially supported by Gentoo, yet, and it's not advisable to mess around with a toolchain's core util if you're new to Gentoo (it's over all no good idea).

Comment: @Andreas oh, really? Does Gentoo use `clang` as a main compiler? I didn't think `gcc` is not supported, because I saw it was available. And [wiki entry for Clang](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Clang) tells me that "not all packages build correctly with it".

Comment: Well, sorry! I forgot one important thing: GCC _4.9_ is not (yet) supported. Gentoo uses GCC, but since everything usually is built from the end-user and thus has to work more or less out-of-the-box (more being better), transition to a more recent version of core components like compiler, libc, etc. usually takes a bit longer with Gentoo.

Answer (score 0):

I trayed Gentoo with gcc-4.9.0. It works very good.
It has compiled only cairo and firefox with gcc-4.8.3.

My flags `march=ivybridge -O2(3) -mfpmath=sse -mavx -mmmx -pipe`.

Sometimes I used `-ffast-math -ftree-vectorize -funroll-loop` (scientific).
Some packages compile only with `~amd64`.

Comment: Hi noob, welcome on unix.stackexchange: the question seems to ask how to install `gcc` more than the always useful information about which flags produce better results. If you mind improve your answer editing it with this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/145600/edit)